# RabbitMQ RPC call works in real life, but doesn't work in tests

Tags: flask, rabbitmq, pika

I have Flask application and implemented RPC in it.

**engine.py**

```
import pickle
import pika
from databasyfacade.rpc import api

__author__ = 'Marboni'

def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    request = pickle.loads(body)
    func = getattr(api, request['func'])
    try:
        result = func(*request['args'])
    except Exception, e:
        response = {
            'status': 'ERROR',
            'error': e
        }
    else:
        response = {
            'status': 'OK',
            'result': result
        }

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
        routing_key=props.reply_to,
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
            correlation_id=props.correlation_id
        ),
        body=pickle.dumps(response)
    )
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


def init(host):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host))

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='facade_rpc')
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(on_request, queue='facade_rpc')
```

**api.py**

```
from databasyfacade.services import profiles_service

__author__ = 'Marboni'

def profile(user_id):
    return profiles_service.profile(user_id)
```

When Flask application initializes, it runs method `init(host)`.

---

Now I need to test how my application responses to RPC calls. So I wrote following RPC client:

**client.py**

```
import pickle
import uuid
import pika

__author__ = 'Marboni'

class RpcClient(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=host))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)

        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_response, no_ack=True, queue=self.callback_queue)


    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body


    def call(self, func, *args):
        request = {
            'func': func,
            'args': args
        }

        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
            routing_key='facade_rpc',
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                reply_to = self.callback_queue,
                correlation_id = self.corr_id,
            ),
            body=pickle.dumps(request))

        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.process_data_events()
        response = pickle.loads(self.response)
        if response['status'] == 'ERROR':
            e = response['error']
            raise e
        else:
            return response['result']
```

Then I wrote test based on Flask-Testing framework. It initializes Flask application between each test method, so we can interact with it.

**tests.py**

```
from databasyfacade.rpc import RpcClient
from databasyfacade.testing import DatabasyTest, fixtures
from databasyfacade.testing.testdata import UserData, ProfileData

__author__ = 'Marboni'

class RpcTest(DatabasyTest):
    @fixtures(UserData, ProfileData)
    def test_profile(self, data):
        rpc = RpcClient(self.app.config['RABBITMQ_HOST'])
        profile = rpc.call('profile', ProfileData.hero.user_id)
        self.assertIsNotNone(profile)
        self.assertEqual(ProfileData.hero.email, profile.email)
```

This test hangs when makes call. It iterates infinitely here:

*From client.py*

```
while self.response is None:
    self.connection.process_data_events()
```

It means that `on_response()` method on client never called.

If I interrupt my tests with CTRL-C, I will see following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../env/bin/nosetests", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 197, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 61, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 74, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kwarg)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 133, in run
    self.runTest(result)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 151, in runTest
    test(result)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_testing.py", line 72, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_testing.py", line 80, in _pre_setup
    self.app = self.create_app()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/databasyfacade/databasyfacade/testing/__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    return app.create_app()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/databasyfacade/databasyfacade/app.py", line 75, in create_app
    init_rpc(app)
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/databasyfacade/databasyfacade/app.py", line 63, in init_rpc
    rpc.init(app.config['RABBITMQ_HOST'])
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/databasyfacade/databasyfacade/rpc/engine.py", line 39, in init
    channel.basic_consume(on_request, queue='facade_rpc')
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 220, in basic_consume
    {'consumer_tag': consumer_tag})])
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1104, in _rpc
    self._wait_on_response(method_frame))
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1124, in _send_method
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 215, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 327, in _handle_read
    if self._read_poller.ready():
  File "/Users/Marboni/Projects/Databasy/databasy-facade/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 66, in ready
    self.poll_timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

---

I tried to run application and access it from separate script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from databasyfacade.rpc.client import RpcClient

rpc = RpcClient('localhost')

profile = rpc.call('profile', 4L)
print profile.email
```

As you can see, code is the same as in test, but in this case it works.

What can be the cause of this issue? May be, it's because Flask-Testing runs both application and client in one process? How to check it / write correct test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause, it's not related with MQ. Remove method accessed database using SQLAlchemy with scoped_session. Problem disappeared after I finalized session [properly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions):

```
Session.remove()
```